# Subscript operator overloading: returning reference problems

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

I'm overloading the subscript operator for the first time and I'm having troubles in returning a reference value.
I followed the rules of thumb from a post in *c++faq tag*, but there's something I'm missing.

```
const T& operator[](int index) const {
    if ((index < 0) || (index > size)) {
                    // provide exception handling for this error
        std::cout << "Error! Index out of bound." << std::endl;
        std::exit(0);
    } else {
        Block* b = head;
        while (b) {
            if (b->position == index)
                return *b->data;

            b = b->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented them in both variants: with `const` return value and `const` function (as above), and without (that is identical except for the two `const` keywords).
The problem is that when I run the test main, it simply crashes. I thought that the bug was in the `return *b->data;` statement, but I can't figure neither which it could be nor if I'm wrong and there are other errors. 
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, `(index > size)` should be `(index >= size)` (or the more "visual" `(size <= index)`), because I guess that the valid range for `index` is `[0, size-1]` (i.e. `[0, size)`). Second, what if the execution never meets the condition `(b->position == index)` and exits the loop when `b` becomes null? Nothing will be returned by the function and that's undefined behavior, you should handle that error case too.

Comment: @gx_ Do you have any suggestion to handle the case of no returning value? I already considered the error, but leaved it for later fix.

Comment: I don't know your code's internals... If that should logically never happen (i.e. if for each valid `index` there's supposed to exist an equal `position` in a `Block` of your (what seems to be a) linked-list) I suppose that you can put an assertion (or print an error and exit like above) after the `while` body (or just before the end of the function body). After you do that, plus the fix from my first comment, does your program still crash? and/or does it print some error message?

Comment: @gx_ Yes, I made your fixes but the program still crashes without any compiler error/warning and without print nothing. Here the code if you have the patience to read it: http://pastebin.com/R6yrfha0. Anyway, thanks for the help you gave me 'till now..

Comment: Erm, why not just use `std::vector`? There's so much to say about your pastebin (BTW you don't show your `main`)... A lot of pointers (with a `new` but no `delete`); `head` is left _uninitialized_ with `Array`'s default constructor (probable cause of crash if you use `head` afterwards); `Block`'s constructor wants a `T*` _pointer_ but you pass it a `T` value (I thought it wouldn't compile but e.g. with `Array<int>` it passes `int()` i.e. `0` which is convertible to a (null) pointer, other probable cause of crash if you try `*data`); copy & destruction aren't handled --running out of characters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a reference on data, I'm not sure if it's what you want, you to return a reference of type T and I'm assuming data is of type T, it should be something like:

```
return b->data;
```

Else, you are returning a reference on the adress of data.

**EDIT**: Corrected a mistake

Comment: What you are saying is contradicted by the link. `->` has higher precedence than `*`.

Comment: If I remove the `*` from the return, I get back this `error: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'int*'`.